# Howto check if a object is connected to another in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Imagine two domain object classes, `A` and `B`. `A` has a bidirectional one-to-many relationship to `B`. `A` is related to thousands of `B`. The relations must be unique, it's not possible to have a duplicate.

To check if an instance of `B` is already connected to a given instance of `A`, we could perform an easy `INNER JOIN` but this will only ensure the already persisted relations.

What about the current transient relations?

```
class A {
   @OneToMany
   private List<B> listOfB;
}
```

If we access the `listOfB` and perform a check of `contains()` this will fetch all the connected instances of `B` lazy from the datasource. I only want to validate them by their primary-key.

Is there an easy solution where I can do things like "*Does this instance of `A` is connected with this instance of `B`?*" without loading all these data into memory and performing a lookup based on collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers. The extra lazy collection did the trick for me. I configured the `@OneToMany` connection with the `LazyCollection` annotation.

```
@IndexColumn(name = "index", base = 1)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
```

The [Hibernate: Extra-lazy collection fetching](https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/java/hibernate-extra-lazy-collection-fetching) article helped me doing this. When you use this option, `#size()`, `#contains()`, `#get()`, etc. do not trigger collection initialization.

Answer (score 1):

i think it can be done in two steps. For transient B's, 
Add your transient
 B's to listOfB also add to a transient 
list too. And do your contains checks in this list.

For your persisted B's, use a query something like,

```
select count(*) from B b where b.a.id = :aId
```

If this
query returns zero, you can say that there isn't a relation
between A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about the last paragraph of your question some more, since the association is bidirectional, I would do a search on your specific instance of B with an association to A.

Comment: It definitely loads all the objects, that's the problem here, we got a performance issue with that. Hibernate creates and initialize all these objects.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you perform `INNER JOIN`?

With default flush mode Hibernate will flush the session before executing query, so that unsaved elements of the collection is not a problem.